# data flux dqmatch function error df_error_invalid_input

Tags: sas

I am getting error while running program in SAS, for example, `DQmatch` function .

```
DQMATCH('India Mumbai rod no2',address text,80,'ENIND')
```

For other matching definition, it's working fine but I am getting error only for this definition.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether to add this as a comment or an answer. I don't use the dqmatch function but the [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/dqclref/63101/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002102796.htm) and other usage [examples](http://www.lexjansen.com/nesug/nesug08/hw/hw05.pdf) I've seen indicate that the second argument should be a quoted literal. If it does not need to be a quoted literal then verify if you're allowed a space in the argument you've supplied.

If none of this helps then I suggest you add the full error message you are getting (if there is any more) and an example of a call to dqmatch that is working.